# Upgrade to 18.04 fails

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

Whn running `do-release-upgrade`

I get the following

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not determine the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state
```

When running `grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`

```
Broken grub-common:amd64 Conflicts on grub-common:i386 < none -> 2.02-2ubuntu8.1 @un uN Ib >
Broken grub2-common:amd64 Conflicts on grub2-common:i386 < none -> 2.02-2ubuntu8.1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsmbios-c2:amd64 Conflicts on libsmbios2v5:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken os-prober:amd64 Conflicts on os-prober:i386 < none -> 1.74ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libcurl4:amd64 Conflicts on libcurl3:amd64 < 7.55.1-1ubuntu2.5 -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken gnome-themes-extra-data:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-themes-standard-data:amd64 < 3.22.3-1ubuntu2 -> 3.22.3-3ubuntu2 @ii umU >
Broken gnome-themes-extra-data:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-themes-standard-data:i386 < none @un H >
Broken librubberband2:amd64 Conflicts on librubberband2v5:amd64 < 1.8.1-6ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
Broken dkms:amd64 Breaks on shim-signed:amd64 < 1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2 | 1.34.9.2+13-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (< 1.34~)
Broken shim-signed:amd64 Depends on grub2-common:amd64 < 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3 -> 2.02-2ubuntu8 @ii umU > (>= 2.02-2ubuntu8.1)
```

It seems grub is correct though

`sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r` shows nothing.

Any suggestions for fixing ?

Comment: Related: [Unable to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, no real error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067331/unable-to-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04-no-real-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same issue. Disabled "pre-released updates", works now

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/852451)

Comment: I actually think this fixes the issue. I did check this to get some WiFi drivers

Comment: @exussum In that case why not accept the answer?

Comment: Hadnt tested it, Was on phone When I posted that. Back on a PC and this is the cause of the issue

Comment: @VolkerSiegel but in the original post the question was "Any suggestions for fixing ?" so that was my answer...

Comment: BTW, this is located in `"Software & Updates" > "Developer Options"`. It was already disabled for me, still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the version numbers, you seem to have unwisely added 18.04 (Bionic) repositories to a 17.10 (Artful) system.

DON'T mix packages from different releases of Ubuntu - doing so will break your system in precisely this way.

Delete the 18.04 sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The release-upgrade tool will recreate the new sources at the appropriate time. Update the package database to reflect the changed sources using `sudo apt update`. Then try the release upgrade again.

If you added non-Ubuntu sources, you might need to uninstall those non-Ubuntu packages. Sometimes the files they provide are different (*file conflict*), or their version number is confusing (*version conflict*).