# Unable to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, no real error?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, lts, do-release-upgrade

I received the notice that there's an update for my desktop install, but I'm unable to do so. There's no real error messages that I can see. I've run `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt upgrade`, and `sudo apt install`, and it gives `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`. This is my screen when I run `do-release-upgrade`:

```
Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Mon Aug 20 20:34:56 2018) ===
```

This is my main.log:

```
2018-08-20 20:34:50,649 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.xenial']'
2018-08-20 20:34:50,649 INFO uname information: 'Linux egwene 4.4.0-133-generic #159-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 07:26:31 UTC 2018 i686'
2018-08-20 20:34:50,862 INFO apt version: '1.2.15ubuntu0.2'
2018-08-20 20:34:50,862 INFO python version: '3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
2018-08-20 20:34:50,864 INFO release-upgrader version '18.04.24' started
2018-08-20 20:34:50,868 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2018-08-20 20:34:51,059 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2018-08-20 20:34:51,111 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2018-08-20 20:34:51,150 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2018-08-20 20:34:54,329 DEBUG lsb-release: 'xenial'
2018-08-20 20:34:54,330 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2018-08-20 20:34:54,331 DEBUG openCache()
2018-08-20 20:34:54,332 DEBUG No such plugin directory: ./plugins
2018-08-20 20:34:54,332 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-08-20 20:34:54,332 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-08-20 20:34:54,332 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-08-20 20:34:54,333 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2018-08-20 20:34:54,333 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2018-08-20 20:34:54,721 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 56038
2018-08-20 20:34:54,721 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2018-08-20 20:34:54,721 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2018-08-20 20:34:54,721 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2018-08-20 20:34:55,529 DEBUG openCache()
2018-08-20 20:34:55,939 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 56038
2018-08-20 20:34:55,940 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2018-08-20 20:34:55,940 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-08-20 20:34:55,940 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-08-20 20:34:55,940 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-08-20 20:34:55,940 DEBUG quirks: running bionicPostInitialUpdate
2018-08-20 20:34:55,940 DEBUG running Quirks.bionicPostInitialUpdate
2018-08-20 20:34:55,951 DEBUG abort called
2018-08-20 20:34:55,951 DEBUG openCache()
2018-08-20 20:34:55,951 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked)
2018-08-20 20:34:56,356 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 56038
```

What could be the problem here?

**Edit**

Using the link provided by WinEunuuchs2Unix, here are my PPA links:

```
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted'
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe'
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse'
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted'
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe'
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse'
'http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner'
```

Comment: I'm comparing the log from my (successful) upgrade; it looks exactly like yours until the line `running Quirks.bionicPostInitialUpdate`. My next line is `MetaPkgs lubuntu-core lubuntu-desktop`.  This log is not informative!

Comment: Um, since you were careful to include it in some of the commands in your question, but not this one, you did do `sudo do-release-upgrade`, right?

Comment: Yes, the two logs are from that. I've done it both with and without sudo, and it gives the exact same output.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` before `sudo do-release-upgrade`? If so can you list all your ppa's with command found in this Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148932/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-repositories-and-ppas-from-the-command-line-into-an

Comment: Did you try using `sudo update-manager` or do you not have a desktop?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  I had. I've edited the post with my PPAs.

Comment: @pbhj I do, and that command did the exact same thing as the command line.

Comment: What's the output of `do-release-upgrade -c`? This should tell you that there is a new release of Ubuntu.
Please also show us your current version by running `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: @Andy `do-release-upgrade -c` gives `New release '18.04.1 LTS' available.`. I've also gotten the GUI popup to upgrade, but it always fails. `lsb_release -a` gives `No LSB modules are available. | Distributor ID: Ubuntu | Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS | Release:        16.04 | Codename:       xenial`

Comment: @aynber okay this looks like it should. Maybe there are packages that need updating before you can upgrade Ubuntu. This command will make sure that all packages are up to do date:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
If the list looks reasonable, press 'Y'. Afterwards, try again to run `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @Andy I've done that several times, both before and after attempting the upgrade. I've even restarted after running the update/upgrade commands. Still no go.

Comment: Found it. Apparently Ubuntu has stopped supporting 32bit architecture. It never threw any sort of message about 32bit/64bit, so it was hard to track down. I ran apt update last night, and several packages threw "unsupported kernel version" errors, which led me in the right direction.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the message === Command detached from window (Mon Aug 20 20:34:56 2018) === comes from the upgrade process running in screen (see man screen) and the virtuel terminal was detached for some reason. It's probably the reason why you cannot see warnigs or error. You can reattach a terminal with the command screen -r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has stopped supporting 32bit desktop systems as of 17.10. The latest version of 32bit is 16.04.5, per https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads .

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo apt remove --purge snapd
```

Tried all options from various threads but above has fixed the problem for me

Comment: Same for me. I saw others reporting the same problem with the same log entry and in this answer ( https://askubuntu.com/a/1100514/512408 ) someone did the hard work of debugging it with strace and the fingers all point to a broken snapd installation.

Comment: This helps in Ubuntu 18.04, in Ubuntu 16.04 however, the problem is in the errors that happen at the end of the ```sudo apt-get update```

Comment: had the exact same problem upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 and this fixed it! So weird.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I had this issue after installing Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL2.
This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

and then upgrade

Sometimes this package is missing or corrupted and the installer has hard time figuring out which version is currently running, There are lots of complains about that if you google it. The same might happen in Debian.

Comment: sometimes this package is missing or corrupted and the installer has hard time figuring out which version is currently running, There are lots of complains about that if you google it.

Comment: Package lsb-core is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source. E: Package 'lsb-core' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

wow so blind I am.

I miss xenial-updates package source.

Expand your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Update xenial

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Then try again. If this is not working I'm out of ideas.

And you know backup 1.

Comment: I already fixed it by just doing a full install, since Ubuntu no longer support 32-bit installations.

Comment: Öhm, my bionic is 32-bit upgrade from xenial