# Can't upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

I need some help. When i try to upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 via update manager, It shows an X mark and closes on the preparing stage. And when i try it via terminal. I get this:

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

EDIT: Oh, And btw. I lost my usb. So i can't do a clean install. And my system is a Dell Latitude E7240.

File `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`:

```
2018-09-26 13:58:15,662 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.xenial']'
2018-09-26 13:58:15,663 INFO uname information: 'Linux rami-Latitude-E7240 4.4.0-135-generic #161~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 28 11:17:49 UTC 2018 x86_64'
2018-09-26 13:58:15,754 INFO apt version: '1.2.10ubuntu1'
2018-09-26 13:58:15,755 INFO python version: '3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160330]'
2018-09-26 13:58:15,756 INFO release-upgrader version '18.04.24' started
2018-09-26 13:58:15,840 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2018-09-26 13:58:16,158 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewGtk3' view
2018-09-26 13:58:16,214 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2018-09-26 13:58:16,234 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2018-09-26 13:58:17,061 DEBUG lsb-release: 'xenial'
2018-09-26 13:58:17,061 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2018-09-26 13:58:17,062 DEBUG openCache()
2018-09-26 13:58:17,062 DEBUG No such plugin directory: ./plugins
2018-09-26 13:58:17,062 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-09-26 13:58:17,062 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-09-26 13:58:17,062 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-09-26 13:58:17,062 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2018-09-26 13:58:17,062 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2018-09-26 13:58:17,342 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 12180
2018-09-26 13:58:17,342 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2018-09-26 13:58:17,343 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2018-09-26 13:58:17,343 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2018-09-26 13:58:17,805 DEBUG openCache()
2018-09-26 13:58:18,083 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 12180
2018-09-26 13:58:18,083 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2018-09-26 13:58:18,083 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-09-26 13:58:18,083 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-09-26 13:58:18,083 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-09-26 13:58:18,084 DEBUG quirks: running bionicPostInitialUpdate
2018-09-26 13:58:18,084 DEBUG running Quirks.bionicPostInitialUpdate
2018-09-26 13:58:18,119 DEBUG abort called
2018-09-26 13:58:18,120 DEBUG openCache()
2018-09-26 13:58:18,120 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked) 
2018-09-26 13:58:18,404 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 12180
```

Comment: What are the contents of file `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`?

Comment: Log time: 2018-09-26 11:31:46.931805 & Log time: 2018-09-26 11:31:47.694061 & Log time: 2018-09-26 11:31:47.970591

Comment: Kind of empty. Well, what about `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`?

Comment: I can't do it. It has too much info

Comment: Edit the question, put the contents there.

Comment: Will do that. Thx

Comment: Did you press `Ctrl+C` in the terminal?

Comment: For what? Why did i need to press it?

Comment: For what I see from the logs, the upgrade process was aborted. If you press this key combination in the terminal, the process will stop. Try to update again, and tell us, if you get  the same the error.

Comment: I got the same error. And I did not touch the keyboard while it was doing the process

Comment: Right, then this is probably the same problem of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067331/unable-to-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04-no-real-error

Comment: Okie. I will go ahead and check it out.

Comment: That page didn't really help me. I really need to get this fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Still researching but running it all under `strace` suggests that the last failure before the Abort is trying to run something `snap` related - `/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9dqwuool/imported/snap debug connectivity` which is dying with `error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/debug: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused`

Ah, in fact, `snap debug connectivity` blows up when run directly, `service snapd status` says `Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit)`; running `service snapd start` results in a status of `Active: active (running)` and then `snap debug connectivity` says `Connectivity status: * PASS`... and then `do-release-upgrade` actually makes progress.

Based on other search results, please note that this *only* applies if your `main.log` goes immediately from `running Quirks.bionicPostInitialUpdate` to `abort called` -- if there's *anything* else in there it's probably not this.

It looks like this might relate to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1780841 (which seems to be what implements the feature that doesn't work here.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Ubuntu 16 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade failed to start.

Using the graphical upgrade tool it stops quickly after 'preparing', not saying anything.

Using do-release-upgrade it stops at:
2019-03-08 23:55:58,515 DEBUG running Quirks.bionicPostInitialUpdate
2019-03-08 23:55:58,524 DEBUG abort called

It proved to be the snap daemon not running (systemctl status snapd) on my system causing the upgrade to fail without further notice.

---

Quick update:

Maybe half an hour after finally getting the do-release-upgrade script to start in the graphical environment a new challenge came up:

Half way after downloading and starting the upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18 the upgrade process stopped completely.

The Unity desktop disappeared (it seemed to me Xorg died, probably when running the update of ubuntu-gnome-desktop).

It brought me back into one of the ASCII consoles.

Trying to run: 'apt install -f' under root to finish the uninstalled packages resulted in a huge amount of dependency issues as the system had already been party upgraded to version 18.

I shut the system down and tried to boot it next day. No more Unity and no more Gnome, it came only up to recovery in the ASCII console.

Having a full backup ready is a useful thing when doing these upgrades, so I decided to restore the system to Ubuntu 16 and wait for a more favourable moment to upgrade it to 18.