# Upgrading from mythbuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, mythtv

I've been trying to upgrade my home theater PC from Mythbuntu 16.04 (the last release of Mythbuntu) for the past few months.  I perform a "do-release-upgrade" and I get this:

```
Reading state information... Done
Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
```

I can't figure out why it's aborting, other than there is no such release  Mythbuntu 18.04.  I'm not seeing anything in the log files indicating why it aborted.  I also removed all the PPAs I had (e.g. mediatree).

Looks like I'll have to start clean with Ubuntu 18.04 and then install MythTV on top of that.  I was hoping to avoid that, but it looks like I have no other choice, except to hold off on the upgrade.

[Updated 08/01/19] Added command and full output, along with output from apt list, per request.

```
jim@goldchannel:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade --mode=desktop
[sudo] password for jim: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,240 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,241 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]     
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]    
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]  
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,
000 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [845
 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [758 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [691 kB]
Fetched 3,619 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

```
jim@goldchannel:~$ apt list --installed | grep hw

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

hwdata/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.267-1ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
lshw/xenial-updates,now 02.17-1.1ubuntu3.6 amd64 [installed]
mythweather/now 2:0.28.2+fixes.20180827.9031599-0ubuntu0mythbuntu2 amd64 [installed,local]
mythweb/now 2:0.28.2+fixes.20180827.9031599-0ubuntu0mythbuntu2 all [installed,local]
python-debtagshw/xenial,xenial,now 2.0.1ubuntu6 all [installed]
```

And output from uname -a and lsb_release -a.

```
jim@goldchannel:~$ uname -a
Linux goldchannel 4.4.0-143201903221420-generic #0+mediatree+hauppauge-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 22 23:58:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

jim@goldchannel:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

[Updated 8/3/19] Added dpkg -l | grep recover, per nobody's request.  (And took out extra spaces for readability.)

```
jim@goldchannel:~$ dpkg -l | grep recover
ii  foremost           1.5.7-6                amd64        forensic program to recover lost files
ii  friendly-recovery  0.2.31ubuntu2.1        all          Make recovery more user-friendly
ii  gddrescue          1.19-2                 amd64        GNU data recovery tool
ii  scalpel            1.60-3                 amd64        fast filesystem-independent file recovery
ii  testdisk           7.0-1                  amd64        Partition scanner and disk recovery tool, and PhotoRec file recovery tool
```

[Updated 8/8/19] Added log file /var/log/dist-upgade/20190808-2242/main.log.

```
2019-08-08 22:38:12,314 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.xenial']'
2019-08-08 22:38:12,314 INFO uname information: 'Linux goldchannel 4.4.0-1432019
03221420-generic #0+mediatree+hauppauge-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 22 23:58:32 UTC 2019 
x86_64'
2019-08-08 22:38:12,717 INFO apt version: '1.2.32'
2019-08-08 22:38:12,717 INFO python version: '3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43
:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
2019-08-08 22:38:12,722 INFO release-upgrader version '18.04.34' started
2019-08-08 22:38:12,804 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2019-08-08 22:38:13,294 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewGtk3' view
2019-08-08 22:38:13,343 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2019-08-08 22:38:13,370 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clo
ne_system_state.tar.gz'
2019-08-08 22:38:19,743 DEBUG lsb-release: 'xenial'
2019-08-08 22:38:19,744 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2019-08-08 22:38:19,748 DEBUG openCache()
2019-08-08 22:38:19,748 DEBUG No such plugin directory: ./plugins
2019-08-08 22:38:19,748 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2019-08-08 22:38:19,748 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPreCacheOpen' are '[]
'
2019-08-08 22:38:19,748 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPreCacheOpen' ar
e '[]'
2019-08-08 22:38:19,748 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2019-08-08 22:38:19,748 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2019-08-08 22:38:20,456 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 89519
2019-08-08 22:38:20,457 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (becaus
e of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2019-08-08 22:38:20,457 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2019-08-08 22:38:20,457 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2019-08-08 22:38:21,608 DEBUG openCache()
2019-08-08 22:38:22,391 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 89519
2019-08-08 22:38:22,391 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2019-08-08 22:38:22,392 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2019-08-08 22:38:22,392 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPostInitialUpdate' ar
e '[]'
2019-08-08 22:38:22,392 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPostInitialUpdat
e' are '[]'
2019-08-08 22:38:22,392 DEBUG quirks: running bionicPostInitialUpdate
2019-08-08 22:38:22,392 DEBUG running Quirks.bionicPostInitialUpdate
2019-08-08 22:38:27,411 DEBUG abort called
2019-08-08 22:38:27,412 DEBUG openCache()
2019-08-08 22:38:28,181 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 89519
```

[Updated 8/12/19] Added the output of dpkg --print-architecture.

```
amd64
```

[Updated 8/15/19] Added output of snap list, per request of nobody.  Also added output of uname -a.

```
jim@goldchannel:~$ snap list
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/snaps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

jim@goldchannel:~$ uname -a
Linux goldchannel 4.4.0-157-generic #185-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 23 09:17:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[Updated 8/18/19] Adding output from systemctl status snapd.socket and contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

```
 jim@goldchannel:~$ systemctl status snapd.socket
Failed to get properties: No such interface '' 

jim@goldchannel:~$ sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
b-rad-ubuntu-kernel_mediatree_hauppauge-xenial.list
heyarje-ubuntu-makemkv-beta-xenial.list
mythbuntu-testing-trusty.list
mythbuntu-ubuntu-0_27-xenial.list
mythbuntu-ubuntu-0_28-xenial.list
plexmediaserver.list
ubuntu-audio-dev-ppa-trusty.list
```

[Updated 8/19/19] I looked at the dist-update log and it seems to gag and blow chunks after the line "quirks: running bionicPostInitialUpdate".  Can't find any more detailed info after that, but it appears I'm not the only one having this problem.  Refer to 
[Unable to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, no real error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067331/unable-to-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04-no-real-error)

Comment: Can you show us the command + full output. also `apt list --installed | grep hw`
Please edit your question for that.

Comment: Certainly.  I just added it to the original post.  I also added output from uname -a and lsb_release -a.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep recover` please.

Comment: Done; added to the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error with snaps.  `systemctl status snapd.socket`

```
snap list
No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.`
```

this is the message you get, if you have no snaps on your system.

remove it. `sudo apt purge snapd`

```
 sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Try again. Be attentive during the upgrade, in bionic is gnome3 the new default desktop. Backup your data.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  The Hauppauge tuner card required a fork of the standard kernel.  I rebooted, selected the standard kernel, typed both steps above, and then attempted a do-release-upgrade.  Still aborted, as it did above.

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` please.

Comment: It's "amd64".  Added to the main post.

Comment: `snap list`  please.

Comment: Added.  Not sure how this will help.  I don't use snaps.

Comment: Ping ping @poltr1

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense to me. What does the ping command have to do with the problem?  snapd.service isn't running because snapd was never installed.